# Django Multiple search views

Tags: python, django

I have three django apps where I want to add a search function. In every search function I need to pass three things. `Selected`, `title` and `url` and I would like to add some details when I want. I think I can compress this code but I don't know how.

Here are my search functions:

article search:

```
def search(request):
    return render(request, "article/search/search.html", {
        "selected": "news",
        "title": "Suche | Artikel",
        "categories": Article.objects.all().order_by("Category").values_list("Category__title", flat=True).distinct(),
        "exists": {k._meta.verbose_name.title(): k.objects.all().exists() for k in [Image, Audio, Video]},
        "any_exists": Image.objects.all().exists() or Audio.objects.all().exists() or Video.objects.all().exists(),
        "url": reverse("ajax:news_article_search")
    })
```

poll search:

```
def search(request):
    return render(request, "poll/search/search.html", {
        "selected": "news",
        "title": "Suche | Umfrage",
        "not_solved_exist": Poll.get_all_able(request).exists(),
        "must_verified_exist": Poll.get_all_able(request).filter(must_verified=True).exists(),
        "for_me_exist": Poll.get_all_able(request).exists(),
        "url": reverse("ajax:poll_poll_search")
    })
```

riddle search:

```
def search(request):
    return render(request, "riddle/search/search.html", {
        "selected": "news",
        "title": "Suche | Rätsel",
        "not_solved_exist": Riddle.objects.filter(solvedsolution__user=request.user).exists() if request.user.is_authenticated else Riddle.objects.filter(solvedsolution__ip=get_client_ip(request)).exists(),
        "url": reverse("ajax:riddle_riddle_search")
    })
```

Comment: When you say "compress this code" do you mean to reduce duplication? Also, if you want a more robust filtering solution, have a look at [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: Yes I want to reduce duplication in this code.